# Bootstrap popover not showing jQuery text input changes made before loading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a bootstrap 2 site that I want a simple form to appear within a popover.

The form is showing correctly,  but if I change the .val of any text inputs before loading the popover,  the changed text doesn't appear.

```
$('#txtOne').val('My New Text');
$('#txtTwo').val('My New Text');

$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
},
content: function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dzr521qs/196/

The text input within the popover should contain "My New Text",  however it still shows the default text of "My Default Text"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: but if I change the .val of any text inputs, where is `change()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuerys `$(element).val()` does not work on invisible elements, i.e having `display:none`.

But you can always set the value of the invisible `<input>` using `attr()` :

```
$('#txtTwo').attr("value", "my all new text");
```

now it works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/k7dunxn4/**